# Как повесить обработчик событий на весь viewport?

Tags: javascript

Стоить задача отловить действие пользователя, когда он мышью выходит за границы viewport. Как это сделать?

Дело в том, что `window.addEventListener('mouseout' ...)` - не работает. Когда я навожу на элемент внутри страницы(на какой-нибудь div) - срабатывает этот обработчик.
Аналогично с `body.addEventListener`.

А мне нужно отловить именно выход за границы моей страницы, например когда пользователь хочет закрыть браузер или вкладку, или свернуть браузер. Как это можно сделать на чистом JS?

Comment: Никак, события не обрабатываются за пределами viewport. По-моему, даже плагины не предоставляют возможностей отследить hover-ры на вкладках.

Comment: А как-же window.onblur ? Это почти подходящий для меня вариант

Comment: Но с вкладками такого не прокатит. Я в смысле про определение момента, когда пользователь пытается отойти, а не когда что-то уже произошло. И window.onblur это внутри документа, а не снаружи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете поймать момент выхода мышки за пределы `document`.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log('mouseleave');
});
```